# How to add query parameters using Gorilla Mux?

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

This is how i build my routes at the time so far using Gorilla Mux. Now i need to add query params to my routes. This is how im doing at this moment:

```
type Route struct {
    Name       string
    Method     string
    Pattern    string
    HandleFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

func NewRouter(sqlDb *data.Data, redisClient *redis.Client) Router {
    return &router{
        sqlDb:       sqlDb,
        redisClient: redisClient,
    }
}

func (r *router) MapRoutes() {
    r.buildUserRoutes()
}

func routesCreation(routes Routes, r *router) {

    for _, route := range routes {
        r.Router.Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandleFunc)
    }
}

var userRoutes = Routes{
    Route{"ping", "GET", "/ping", handler.Ping},
}
```

This is what i tried, adding a slice of string as a field on `Route` struct but it did not worked:

```
type Route struct {
    Name       string
    Method     string
    Pattern    string
    HandleFunc http.HandlerFunc
    Queries    []string
}

func NewRouter(sqlDb *data.Data, redisClient *redis.Client) Router {
    return &router{
        sqlDb:       sqlDb,
        redisClient: redisClient,
    }
}

func (r *router) MapRoutes() {
    r.buildUserRoutes()
}

func (r *router) buildUserRoutes() {

    p := []string{"a", "b"}

    var userRoutes = Routes{
        Route{"ping", "GET", "/ping", handler.Ping, p},
}

func routesCreation(routes Routes, r *router) {

    for _, route := range routes {
        r.Router.Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandleFunc).
            Queries(route.Queries)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add query params with this config for routes creations?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the `...`, i.e. `Queries(route.Queries...)`. And keep in mind that the content of `route.Queires` must be a "sequence of key/value pairs". e.g. `[]string{"key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", etc.}`.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, now the Queries(route.Queries...) is solved, now speaking of the "sequence of key/value pairs", i need to set the value of each key from the request and not setting it on the []string